# What does this 'or' do on the left hand side of a PHP assignment statement?

Tags: php, variable-assignment

I am working on some OAuth stuff and found this interesting line of code:

```
$port or $port = ($scheme == 'https') ? '443' : '80';
```

I a not familiar with an or keyword being on the left hand side of an assignment statement.

I would expect
    $a or = ($b=$c);
would equate to
    $a = $a or ($b=$c);
in a similar manner to
    $str.=" Append this to str";
equates to
    $str=$str."Append this to str";

Searching for 'or' in the help renders many many results! Hence I have turned to stackoverflow....

Can someone please inform me what the 'or' keyword on the left hand side of an assignment does.

In context the whole function is:

```
public static function php_self($dropqs = true) {
    $url = sprintf ( '%s://%s%s', empty ( $_SERVER ['HTTPS'] ) ? (@$_SERVER ['SERVER_PORT'] == '443' ? 'https' : 'http') : 'http', $_SERVER ['SERVER_NAME'], $_SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'] );

    $parts = parse_url ( $url );

    $port = $_SERVER ['SERVER_PORT'];
    $scheme = $parts ['scheme'];
    $host = $parts ['host'];
    $path = @$parts ['path'];
    $qs = @$parts ['query'];

    $port or $port = ($scheme == 'https') ? '443' : '80';

    if (($scheme == 'https' && $port != '443') || ($scheme == 'http' && $port != '80')) {
        $host = "$host:$port";
    }
    $url = "$scheme://$host$path";
    if (! $dropqs)
        return "{$url}?{$qs}";
    else
        return $url;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is equivalent to the following:

```
if (!$port) {
    $port = ($scheme == 'https') ? '443' : '80';
}
```

It uses short-circuiting of the `or` operator to define `$port` if it is not already defined; if the first expression in `A or B` evaluates to `true`, then the second expression does not need to be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

It would essentially be saying the same as:

```
if ($port==0) { 
  $port = ($scheme == 'https') ? '443' : '80';
}
```

A pair of expressions by themselves with the boolean or will evaluate the left value and if it is true will stop there. If the left value is false it will then go on to evaluate the righthand value.  So,

```
$a or $b
```

will evaluate as $a when $a is a boolean true value and will evaluate as $b when $a is boolean false.

Although it works, it goes against common coding practices. It could be written more clearly as I have shown, for example.